# A reference to a retained fragment in a UI fragment. How can the UI fragment be deleted from memory after I rotate the screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-management, screen-rotation

I'm reading the [FragmentRetainInstance sample.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.java)
There is the variable `RetainedFragment mWorkFragment` in `UiFragment`. So how can a `UiFragment` be deleted from memory after I rotate the screen? As far as I understand, `mWorkFragment` is a reference to something that survives across screen rotations and other configuration changes.

**Update #1**

I rotated the screen and pressed Initiate GC, and then pressed Dump heap. I saw the number of `UiFragment` instances was 1. Why? I expected to see 2: 1 for the current orientation and 1 for the previous orientation.

**Initiate GC:**

[image]

**Heap dump:**

[image]

Comment: `UiFragment` is not retained. If it's retained, it will not be recreated when the host Activity is recreated, which is how `Fragment#setRetainInstance(...)` works. So, after you rotate screen and init a gc, previous `UiFragment` instance should be garbage-collected.

Comment: *how can a UiFragment be deleted from memory* - The GC will start from a GC root(which that UiFragment instance isn't) and then traverse its references(and so on) to see which objects are still needed. So the mWorkFragment reference doesn't mater because there isn't an object long lived holding a reference to the UiFragment instance to keep it alive.

Comment: @Luksprog, as far as I understand from your comment, the GC traverses objects starting from the root (possibly the class `Application`) and then determines that `UiFragment` is unreachable (no references after a config change). So it can be deleted. `UiFragment` a root of an unreachable subtree, and `mWorkFragment` is a child of `UiFragment`. If the root is unreachable, all its children are unreachable. Right?

Comment: You're right. If you want to see a memory leak, in the sample above, place a break point inside the activity's onCreate() and then change RetainedFragment to remove the line *mProgressBar = null;* in onDetach(). Debug the app, the first time you hit the break point simply continue the app(there are no fragments created yet) and then rotate the phone. You'll hit the break point again in onCreate(), at this time if you look at the retained fragment instance you'll see that mProgressBar isn't null and it's leaking the previous activity until onActivityCreated() is reached.

Comment: @Luksprog, please combine your comments and write an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the UiFragment from the sample you linked to isn't leaked. It does indeed hold a reference to the RetainedFragment which survives the configuration change but that reference doesn't matter. The GC will start from a GC root and from there it traverses the objects following the references it finds inside the objects. As the UiFragment isn't referenced from something that lives(like the RetainedFragment) it will be outside of the hierarchy of live objects and will be eligible for  garbage collection.

If you want to see a memory leak, in the sample you linked to, remove the line *mProgressBar = null;* from the in onDetach() callback of the RetainedFragment. With this change the RetainedFragment will hold a reference to the UiFragment(actually is the old activity along with all of its data) making the old Context instance to stay alive, at least until the onActivityCreated() callback of the RetainedFragment is called(inside onActivityCreated() mProgressBar will be cleared and made to point to the restored UiFragment's ProgressBar).